# Can't get this element width to be 100%

Tags: php, css, wordpress

He I can't get this width to go to 100% any idea how to fix this? I tried .wapf-field-row .wapf-field-container:last-child { width: 100%; but does not work.

```
<div class="wapf-field-container wapf-field-select" style="width:39%;" for="5ddd58585be2f">
```

Here is the link https://annafactory.peachandhoney.nl/product/small-animal-harness/?

Comment: Maybe remove `style="width:39%;` ?

Answer (score 1):

The `style` attribute of an element will always override any CSS applied somewhere else.

If you want to control the width of the `div` with CSS, you will therefore need to delete the `style` attribute and use CSS only.

Comment: Not always, properties with `!important` will override style attribute properties, unless you use `!important` within style attribute

Comment: @ZohirSalak That is true, thank you for reminding me! However, using the `!important` statement can get quite messy over time, I would still recommend doing it as I described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this properties on the parent element:

[image]

And remove the width properties from the .wapf-field-container class, and the respective style element.

[image]

And it should look like this:

[image]